# How do I reformat a date in format dd.MM.yyyy in Watson Assistant?

Tags: watson-assistant

I am just asking if there is a possibility to reformat a date in format **dd.MM.yyyy** to **yyyy-MM-dd** so the Watson Assistant is able to work with it?

e.g.: **01.07.2020** to **2020-07-01**

The input is not changeable.

I am thankful for the answers as given. I realised that I didnt ask the question properly. I already get an input from an backend system which I cant change. I now need to work with it in the format as given above. How can I change the format directely inside the Watson Assistant?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that `dd.mm.yyyy` is a wrong format for date as `m` specifies a minute. To specify a month, you need to use `M`.

I recommend you use [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Format of input date string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

        // A sample date string
        String strDate = "20.10.2020";

        // Parse the sample date string to LocalDate
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-20
```

Note that your desired format (i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`) is exactly the same format in which [LocalDate#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) returns a string and therefore, you do not need to specify a format for the output string.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple. **Try this code below.**

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
        
        public class FormateDate {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
                String date_s = "01.07.2020";
                LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(date_s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
                String newDate = datetime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                System.out.println(newDate);
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [rich set of modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

Comment: Better. There are still two improvements needed: (1) You have to use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime` as there is no time part in the given string. (2) You do not need a formatter for `yyyy-MM-dd` format when you have an instance of `LocalDate`. Just do `String newDate = localDateInstance.toString()`. Check the link in my answer for details.

Comment: I just added that because if he wanted any other formate in the future he can change anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfNew = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdfOld = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateOld ="01.07.2020";
String dateNew = sdfNew.format(sdfOld.parse(dateOld));
```

Comment: I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [rich set of modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)